# How do I stretch my texture evenly over my entire model?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

I have a problem with the texture on the object created from the curve. It was modeled from a bezier curve, I changed the bevel value and converted it to a mesh. However, in some places the texture is "thicker" than in the others (because of my model has a non-uniform distribution of edges).

[image: render]
[image: blender]

How do I make the texture stretch out evenly on the entire model?

Comment: This is rather strange texture which may cause some visual (or not only) artifacts on rendered model. I would add UV Grid texture for testing first for testing purposes. When it would be clear that texture is applied correctly  I would start testing main image texture.

Comment: http://iv.pl/images/56249827061880863617.png I was thinking about simplifying a bit the model and working on the image editor, but I think that it can not entirely act or takes too much time...

Comment: Try the Texture Atlas addon

Comment: After many attempts I got this: http://iv.pl/images/37831286205574115257.png  (+ Solidify Modifier) but as can be seen it isn't a final effect. I will try this Texture Atlas addon (I hope it isn't too advanced thing because I'm kinda a newbie in blender...)